# DAO.af browsable aggregated tags

Tags: app, tags, javascript, coffeescript

[image: Text]

### About

goal is to learn skills faster by browsing the aggregated concepts.  so you absorb big ideas before diving in.  learn passively. its for everyone.

analyzes SE posts with IBM watson and allows browsing posts by the tags.

#### License

Closed source, eventually open.  free to all.

#### Download

[www.dao.af](https://www.dao.af)

no logins, just viewing

#### Platform

web

### Contact

dm me here or at info@dao.af

### Code

meteorjs, coffeescript, mongo.  closed source for now but happy to talk shop.